# Union types and iterating over an array

Tags: typescript, typing

I have an interface like this:

```
interface foo {a: "first", b: "second"}
```

I'm infering types using a function like:

```
const myFunc = <P extends keyof foo>(prop: P, value:SomeObject[P]) => {
return console.log(P +":" + value)
}
```

Then I do this:

```
Object.keys({a: "something", b: "somethingelse"}).map((x, id) => {
 myFunc(a, "randomtext")
})
```

I get an error:
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b"'.

Why does this happen?

Comment: `console.log(P +":" + value)` - this does not make sense when `P` is a type, since it does not exist at runtime.

Comment: thanks @kaya3, agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Return type of Object.keys is always string[] no matter the parameter passed to it

Comment: Ak okay got it. Thank yo. How would you solve the situation above?

Comment: `if (x === "a" | x === "b") myFunc(x, "randomtext") else // do error handling`

Comment: okay thank you. This feels like an increase in code unnecessarily. Is there a different approach I could take to avoid this?